Discriminant of a monic polynomial with integer coefficients
Let $f=a_0x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+...+a_n,n>1$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients. For $a_0=1$ or $a_n=1$,it is well known that its discriminant $D(f)=4k$ or $D(f)=4k+1$,$k\in{Z}$.Will the discriminant have the same form for any integers $a_0\neq1$ and $a_n\neq1$?

See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4217627 and https://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/ims/bull24/bull24_12-19.pdf (Theorem 1.5), for instance.

@RichardStanley Dear SZR! Thank you very much for the information.
